# What happens when Activity is paused while it's waiting for data from the Internet?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-volley, onpause

What happens if an **ActivityA** makes a Volley request (ASAIK, Volley request runs not on the UI Thread), and let's say that the volley request ask for a lot of data.
Volley request has a callback method named **onResponse**, that contains the JSON Objected returned as a response, and this method runs on the UI-Thread. inside this method we will parse the object, make *ProgressBar* visibilty to *GONE* and add the items into *ReyclerView* that is part of the **ActivityA**.
While the request is in progress, we are showing a circled progress bar. Now (Before the response was returned) user decided to "leave" temporarily the application (so **onPause** runs). What will happen when the result from the server arrive? Does trying to update the UI will cause an Exception, or the UI Thread and the **ActivityA** still alive?
If they are alive so what will happen when the user will return to application? Is he still see the *progressBar*, or the *RecycelrView* filled with the items from the JSONResponse?

Comment: Until your Activity is still alive in the memory, your code will update the UI and if the user returns to your Activity, the user will see the updated UI.

Comment: @just, Does it mean that all the data is being updated by the main UI Thread, and the screen is being render, only when the user return to application/Activity?

Comment: As far as I know yes. But lets try it out ;)

Comment: @just . Ok :) Thanks